# Edit Button Difficulties using Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, edit

I'm new to the coding world. I'm trying to incorporate an edit button. I got the button to show up while the user swipes to the right but I'm having trouble getting the edit button to work. When pressed, it should bring up the table were the user first input the data but with the information already placed in the fields.

For example: user fills in the artist, album and release date, the edit button should take them back to where they first put in the information but with the info already in place.

Here's the code I used for the edit button:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?


{
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Update", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)
    })
    modifyAction.title = "Edit"
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .blue

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
}
```

And here's the code for adding the content:

```
@IBOutlet var artisttextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var albumtextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var releasedatePicker: UIDatePicker!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    releasedatePicker.minimumDate = Date()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func saveTapped( _ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    let artist = artisttextfield.text ?? ""
    let album = albumtextfield.text ?? ""
    let releasedate = releasedatePicker.date

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let newRelease = Release_Date(context: context)
    newRelease.artist = artist
    newRelease.album = album
    newRelease.release_date = releasedate as NSDate?
    newRelease.release_dateId = UUID().uuidString

    if let uniqueId = newRelease.release_dateId {
        print("The freshreleaseId is \(uniqueId)")
    }

    do {
        try context.save()
        let message = "\(artist)'s new album \(album) releases Today!"
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.body = message
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day],
            from: releasedate)
        dateComponents.hour = 09
        dateComponents.minute = 00
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents,
            repeats: true)
        if let identifier = newRelease.release_dateId {

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                content: content, trigger: trigger)
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not save because of \(error).")
    }

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("Added a Release Date!")
    print("Artist: \(newRelease.artist)")
    print("Album: \(newRelease.album)")
    print("Release Date: \(newRelease.release_date)")
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here's viewWillAppear

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = Release_Date.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Release_Date>

    let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "album", ascending: true)
    let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "artist", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
    do {
        freshreleases = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not fetch because of error: \(error).")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than "I'm having trouble getting the edit button to work"? Are you unsure how to show the input fields, are they not being saved to CoreData, are they not showing up correctly in the other view, etc?

Comment: The edit button is there, I'm having trouble getting it linked back to the table view controller above and have it show the already saved data.

Comment: In your table view controller, do you refresh/reload the data from CoreData in either viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear?

Comment: I just edited the original post to add the viewWillAppear code that I have